# BigDecimal behavior in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         System.out.println(new BigDecimal(58.34));
    }
}
```

If I run above given program in Java, it is giving me output like:
`58.340000000000003410605131648480892181396484375`

Why is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the **[BigDecimal.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java#BigDecimal.%3Cinit%3E%28double%29)** best explains this feature.

API say's

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal
>   representation of the double's binary floating-point value. The scale
>   of the returned BigDecimal is the smallest value such that (10scale ×
>   val) is an integer.

**Notes:**

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One
>   might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>   BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>   a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>   matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>   that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>   0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
>
> **The String constructor**, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable: writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates a BigDecimal which
>   is exactly equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is
>   generally recommended that the String constructor be used in
>   preference to this one.
>
> When a **double must be used as a source for a BigDecimal**, note that
>   this constructor provides an exact conversion

Comment: Hi @Ankur. really very nice explained :) Thanks. when should be use `public BigDecimal(double val)` contractor?  Any relevant example?

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia answer edited, basically should be used when you need the exact conversion of passed in double value, will recommend you to read the docs , i have provided you in the links

Answer (score 4):

You pass a `double` when you construct the `BigDecimal` so the precision is already lost. Easiest fix is probably something like

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("58.34"));
```

Output is

```
58.34
```

Answer (score 3):

This will cause due to `double` value

```
 System.out.println(new BigDecimal(58.34));
                                    ^^^
```

To avoid this you can use String value

```
 System.out.println(new BigDecimal("58.34"));
```